# jQuery AutoComplete and Change interactions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am having trouble getting a form to behave as required - not sure if it's an error in coding or approach.
I have a Name field that is set up with jQuery's autocomplete. When an option is selected, an ID field is also populated. This is fine.
The issue I have is I need to clear the ID field id the name field changes as it will no longer be the correct ID. I tried using jQuery's change trigger, but it also fires after autocomplete - or at least, when the name field loses focus after autocomplete - so the ID is always removed.

```
$('#MgrName').autocomplete({
        source:'auto_name.php',
        delay: 100,
        minLength:3,
        select:function(evt, ui)
            {
            // when a name is selected populate fields
            this.form.MgrID.value = ui.item.empid;
            this.form.MgrName.value = ui.item.empname;
            }
        });
$('#MgrName').change(function(){
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        $('#MgrID').val('');
        });
```

I'm thinking I could store the contents of the name field in a variable and only clear the ID if the field no longer matches the variable. Is this the best way, or is there a more elegant solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

i think you may try this,

```
$(document).on("change", "#MgrName", function(){
   alert( "Handler for change called." );
        $('#MgrID').val('');
});
```

insted this,

```
$('#MgrName').change(function(){
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        $('#MgrID').val('');
        });
```